# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') error when i try to run this code for Linear Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nan

dataset:http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csvi have purposely added some null values for my requirement

```
d_with_null=d[['fixed acidity','volatile acidity','citric acid','residual sugar','chlorides','free 
sulfur dioxide','total sulfur dioxide','density','pH','sulphates','alcohol','quality']]

d_without_null=d_with_null.dropna()

trainx=d_without_null.iloc[:,0:-1]
trainx=trainx.astype(np.float64,copy=False)

trainy=d_without_null.iloc[:,-1]
trainy = trainy.astype(np.float64,copy=False)

test = d_with_null.iloc[:,0:-1]
test=test.astype(np.float64,copy=False)
print(test)

from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr=linear_model.LinearRegression()
lr.fit(trainx,trainy)
predict=pd.DataFrame(lr.predict(test))
predict.columns=['fixed acidity','chlorides','density']
print(predict)
```

error :Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Comment: Maybe you could include the actual error print so it would show from which line the error originated from. Also what is actually the question?